# How to use XPath function name() on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, xpath

If I use the following query, it shows `ERROR:  invalid XPath expression`

The query is `SELECT xpath('/foo/*/name()', '<foo><bar>test</bar></foo>')`

I would get a list of node names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer: `SELECT xpath('name()', unnest(xpath('/foo/*', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>')))`