# How to get name of an element using xpath in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, xpath

I have tried this

```
select xpath('name()', unnest(xpath('/foo/*', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>')));
```

As suggested in other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276631/how-to-use-xpath-function-name-on-postgresql), but I just get two empty rows as response.

In addition I have tried

```
select unnest(xpath('name(/foo/*)', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'));
```

But it returns only one row with response as `bar`.

Is there anyway I could get the query to return two rows with result `bar`, `zar` using Xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the xpath function `text()` to extract the elements' contents:

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('/foo/*/text()','<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'));

 unnest 
--------
 test
 test1
(2 Zeilen)
```

To list the element names either use a subquery / CTE or use two `unnest()`, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  unnest(xpath('local-name(./*)',
  unnest(xpath('/foo/node()', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'))));

 unnest 
--------
 bar
 zar
(2 Zeilen)
```

Comment: I would like to get the element name, not the text in the element.

Comment: @bharathp I see.. can you try my last edit?

Answer (score 2):

I find `xmltable()` easier to work with if the output should be rows:

```
with data (content) as (
  values ('<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'::xml)
)  
select x.*
from data
  cross join xmltable('/foo/*' passing content
                       columns 
                         item text path 'name()', 
                         value text path '.') as x
```

Output is:

```
item | value
-----+------
bar  | test 
zar  | test1
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get it only using Xpath? I would like to write index on xml document and I would like to index all the children under the element `foo`. Not sure if it somehow possible to index using xmltable.

Comment: @bharathp: no, that's not possible with xmltable. But you can't really create an index that would support the `unnest()` call  result either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `name()` function to extract the tag name:

```
select xpath('name(/*)', x)
FROM unnest(
        xpath(
           '/foo/*',
           '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'
        )
     ) AS xml(x);

 xpath 
═══════
 {bar}
 {zar}
(2 rows)
```